# How to draw a graph on a sphere using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to make some TiKz graphics for a project I am working on and I am a little stuck. What I am looking for is to be able to draw some planar graphs on a sphere's surface? Any help would be awesome

Comment: I think Asymptote would probably be better for this. But either way, a simple(!) example of what you want to achieve would be helpful.